# SPARQL query. order of triple patterns

Tags: sparql

Consider a SPARQL aggregation query with a `where` clause composed of only triple patterns and `filter` statements.

Does the order of the triple patterns or the order of the `filters` affect the results (not the performance)? I am quite convinced it doesn't affect the validity of the results. But maybe someone can clarify why? Also, does the order of the variables in the `group by` affect the result's validity? I don't think so either but maybe someone can clarify why?

**The following example is just for clarification; I am asking generally.**

The query counts the number of people grouped by their eye color and country and applies a couple of `filters`. The query contains only these four triple patterns *(each line ending by a dot is a triple pattern, i.e., a triple with variables)*

```
?p wdt:P26 ?human.
?p wdt:P27 ?country.
?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
?human wdt:P1340 ?eyeColor.
```

and these two `filters`:

```
FILTER (?country != wd:Q142)
FILTER (?eyeColor != wd:Q17122705)
```

The **`WHERE`** clause doesn't contain any `OPTIONAL`, `UNION`, `MINUS`,... or any other constructor; only triple patterns and filters.

```
SELECT ?eyeColor (COUNT(?human) AS ?count) ?country
WHERE
{
    ?p wdt:P26 ?human.
    ?p wdt:P27 ?country.
    ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
    ?human wdt:P1340 ?eyeColor.
    FILTER (?country != wd:Q142)
    FILTER (?eyeColor != wd:Q17122705)
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
GROUP BY ?eyeColor ?country
```

My question again: if we change the order of the six elements in the **`WHERE`** clause in any way, does that affect the result (not only in this query but also for similar ones in terms of structure)? The same question about whether the order of the variables in the `GROUP BY` might affect the results, for example `GROUP BY ?country ?eyeColor` instead of `GROUP BY ?eyeColor ?country`. Again, I am asking in general, not only for this case query.

Comment: Give code (query) examples to clarify your question.

Comment: I added an example, but it is only for clarification, I am asking abou th concept in general.

Comment: With no query optimizer, clearly the order of FILTERs might affect the execution performance. AFAIK, all triple stores do some query planning + optimization, especially filter push etc. similar to SQL databases. A different order of groups is a totally thing, this clearly can influence the result as you're creating and aggregating different groups.

Comment: Regarding order of triples and filters, I only ask about the result, please forget any performance/optimization details.

Comment: Regarding the grouping, why will it affect? Does the number of Italian people with blue eye(group by ?country ?eyeColor)s change if I ask for blue eyes and Italian (group by ?eye Color ?country) why will the membership of a solution to a group change with the order?

Answer (score 3):

No, the order does not change the results for tripe patterns and filters only.

All filters happen at the end of the {} block they are in (an optimizer may move them but must not change the result).

A number of triple patterns "subject predicate object" will result in the same results regardless of order.

SERVICE is not a triple pattern.

`wikibase:label` is special to wikidata, not the SPARQL spec anyway.

Including any of the graph pattern operations like SERVICE or OPTIONAL.

See the SPARQL algebra the spec or sparql.org to see the algebra.